# Error with using STR command in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm having an issue moving a value from a register into a memory location. It's pretty easy. I first move the format string and value of `abc` into the correct locations and call `printf`. The next block is where I have an issue. I call `adr r1, abc` to get the location of `abc` into `r1`. I then initialize the register `r4` to 10. When I try to store the value of `r4` into the location of `r1`, which is where `abc` is, I get a segfault. I seriously don't know what's going wrong. I feel like the address of `abc` is wrong because it's segfaulting, but I can't tell.
The code is listed below:

```
    .section .text
    .global main
main:
    push {lr}

    ldr r1, abc
    ldr r0, =print_str
    bl printf

    adr r1, abc
    mov r4, #10
    str r4, [r1]

    ldr r1, abc
    ldr r0, =print_str
    bl printf

    pop {lr}
    bx lr

print_str: .asciz "%d\n"
abc: .word 400
```

Comment: You need to put your data into the `.data` section, as `.text` is not writable.

Comment: although it is likely you are writing to .text is the problem. but you have not given enough information specifying arm tells us almost nothing, need to know the chip or the core, and what address space this code is (is it ram or rom/flash, etc).  Even being in flash doesnt mean you cant str to write the value, it depends...(on the chip/situation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the output below what you were looking for?
Not sure of the purpose of your prog.
Your code below with some modificationsto mitigate seg fault but that's it.

```
.data
        print_str: .asciz "%d\n"                                                                                                                                                                     abc: .word 400
.text
    .global main
main:
    push {lr}

    ldr r1,=abc
    ldr r0, =print_str
    bl printf

    ldr r1,=abc
    mov r4, #10
    str r4, [r1]

    ldr r1,=abc
    ldr r0,=print_str
    bl printf

    pop {lr}
    bx lr
```

output:

```
$ ./T94j0
132600
132600
```